# Create vxlan - RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vlan

I knew nothing of vxlan until about 30 minutes ago, however I've come up with an issue installing OpenStack, which is vxlan related.

Trying to create a vxlan on an interface on Ubuntu 14.04 (kernel 3.14.32):

```
ip link add vxlan10 type vxlan id 10 group 239.0.0.10 ttl 4 dev eth0
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

Google is throwing up relatively no information on this - it does not seem to be a common problem.

Admittedly the command above may not be correct, as I've taken an example from elsewhere.  However, I'm not sure if this is a hardware or kernel support issue?

Comment: You also need to update iproute2, which will be quite difficult on 14.04 LTS. Use a distribution more current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was caused by custom kernel from server provider (OVH) without vxlan support.  Switched to generic kernel and vxlan support is working.